# Problem with the dpkg after installing java 8 in Linux Mint

Tags: java, linux, dpkg

I recently installed java 8 in linux mint 19 but after this, when I use sudo apt install [something], the system throw me this error:

```
Configurando install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231/jre/bin: not found
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete install-info (--configure):
instalado install-info paquete post-installation guión el subproceso devolvió un error con estado de salida 127
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I already try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f` but the same error is prompted.

Comment: is these paths existing on the machine? `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_231/jre/bin`

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your /etc/environment with text editor and add last quote (") to it.
For example with Nano:

sudo nano /etc/environment

**change**

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171
```

**to**

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171"
```

Press Ctrl+O to save, then Ctrl+X to quit.